# Stiff ODE-solver

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I need an ODE-solver for a stiff problem similar to MATLAB ode15s.

For my problem I need to check how many steps (calculations) is needed for different initial values and compare this to my own ODE-solver.

I tried using

```
solver = scipy.integrate.ode(f)
solver.set_integrator('vode', method='bdf', order=15, nsteps=3000)
solver.set_initial_value(u0, t0)
```

And then integrating with:

```
i = 0
while solver.successful() and solver.t<tf:
    solver.integrate(tf, step=True)
    i += 1
print(i)
```

Where `tf` is the end of my time interval.

The function used is defined as:

```
def func(self, t, u):
    u1 = u[1]
    u2 = mu * (1-numpy.dot(u[0], u[0]))*u[1] - u[0]
    return numpy.array([u1, u2])
```

Which with the initial value `u0 = [ 2, 0]` is a stiff problem.

This means that the number of steps should not depend on my constant `mu`.

But it does.

I think the `odeint`-method can solve this as a stiff problem - but then I have to send in the whole `t`-vector and therefore need to set the amount of steps that is done and this ruins the point of my assignment.

Is there anyway to use `odeint` with adaptive stepsize between two `t0` and `tf`?

Or can you see anything I miss in the use of the `vode`-integrator?

Comment: I don't understand why you say that the number of steps should not depend on the constant `mu`.   `vode` is an adaptive solver.  Anything that changes the system of equations could change number number of steps required.

Comment: For a *stiff problem* the number of steps can be much lower because longer steps can be taken.

Saying that it doesn't depend is perhaps a bit harsh.
I can do the same calculations in MATLAB with `ode15s` with 40-100 steps for mu > 10000.

While it takes 1.2 million steps for me to calculate mu = 1000 in my python example.

Comment: I'm seeing something similar; changing methods between 'adams' and 'bdf' doesn't change the number of steps by very much.  (By the way, there is no point in using `order=15`; the maximum order of the `'bdf'` method of the `'vode'` solver is 5 (and the maximum order of the `'adams'` solver is 12).  If you leave the argument out, it should use the maximum by default.)

Comment: Okay, thank you for trying :) 

I realized the order thing when reading the docs - was looking at this before, must be a typo! https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html#general-purpose-equivalents

Comment: `odeint` is a wrapper of LSODA.  `ode` also provides a wrapper of LSODA: change `'vode'` to `'lsoda'`.  Unfortunately the `'lsoda'` solver ignores
the `step=True` argument of the `integrate` method.

Comment: The `'lsoda'` solver does *much* better. You can get an upper bound on the number of steps that were used by initializing `tvals = []`, and in `func`, do `tvals.append(t)`.  At the end, set `tvals = np.unique(tvals)`.  The length of `tvals` tells you the number of time values at which your function was evaluated.
That's not exactly what you want, but it does show a *huge* difference
between using the `'lsoda'` solver and the `'vode'` solver with
method `'bdf'`.  The number of steps used by the `'lsoda'` solver is
on the same order as you quoted for matlab.  (I used `mu=10000`, `tf = 10`.)

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you post the suggestion as an answer so I can accept it? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm seeing something similar; with the `'vode'` solver, changing methods between `'adams'` and `'bdf'` doesn't change the number of steps by very much. (By the way, there is no point in using `order=15`; the maximum order of the `'bdf'` method of the `'vode'` solver is 5 (and the maximum order of the 'adams' solver is 12). If you leave the argument out, it should use the maximum by default.)

`odeint` is a wrapper of LSODA. `ode` also provides a wrapper of LSODA:
change `'vode'` to `'lsoda'`. Unfortunately the `'lsoda'` solver ignores
the `step=True` argument of the `integrate` method.

The `'lsoda'` solver does *much* better than `'vode'` with `method='bdf'`.
You can get an upper bound on
the number of steps that were used by initializing `tvals = []`,
and in `func`, do `tvals.append(t)`.  When the solver completes, set
`tvals = np.unique(tvals)`.  The length of `tvals` tells you the
number of time values at which your function was evaluated.
This is not exactly what you want, but it does show a *huge* difference
between using the `'lsoda'` solver and the `'vode'` solver with
method `'bdf'`.  The number of steps used by the `'lsoda'` solver is
on the same order as you quoted for matlab in your comment.  (I used `mu=10000`, `tf = 10`.)

*Update*:  It turns out that, at least for a stiff problem, it make a huge difference for the `'vode'` solver if you provide a function to compute the Jacobian matrix.

The script below runs the `'vode'` solver with both methods, and it
runs the `'lsoda'` solver.  In each case, it runs the solver with and without the Jacobian function.  Here's the output it generates:

```
vode   adams    jac=None  len(tvals) = 517992
vode   adams    jac=jac   len(tvals) = 195
vode   bdf      jac=None  len(tvals) = 516284
vode   bdf      jac=jac   len(tvals) = 55
lsoda           jac=None  len(tvals) = 49
lsoda           jac=jac   len(tvals) = 49
```

The script:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import ode


def func(t, u, mu):
    tvals.append(t)
    u1 = u[1]
    u2 = mu*(1 - u[0]*u[0])*u[1] - u[0]
    return np.array([u1, u2])


def jac(t, u, mu):
    j = np.empty((2, 2))
    j[0, 0] = 0.0
    j[0, 1] = 1.0
    j[1, 0] = -mu*2*u[0]*u[1] - 1
    j[1, 1] = mu*(1 - u[0]*u[0])
    return j


mu = 10000.0
u0 = [2, 0]
t0 = 0.0
tf = 10

for name, kwargs in [('vode', dict(method='adams')),
                     ('vode', dict(method='bdf')),
                     ('lsoda', {})]:
    for j in [None, jac]:
        solver = ode(func, jac=j)
        solver.set_integrator(name, atol=1e-8, rtol=1e-6, **kwargs)
        solver.set_f_params(mu)
        solver.set_jac_params(mu)
        solver.set_initial_value(u0, t0)

        tvals = []
        i = 0
        while solver.successful() and solver.t < tf:
            solver.integrate(tf, step=True)
            i += 1

        print("%-6s %-8s jac=%-5s " %
              (name, kwargs.get('method', ''), j.func_name if j else None),
              end='')

        tvals = np.unique(tvals)
        print("len(tvals) =", len(tvals))
```

Comment: @davidwessman I updated my answer to include an explicitly computed Jacobian matrix.  It makes a big difference.

Comment: wouldn't `jac = lambda t, u, mu: [[0.0, 1.0], [-mu*2*u[0]*u[1] - 1, mu*(1 - u[0]*u[0])]]` be much more efficient?

Comment: Try it and find out.  If you do, be sure to measure the time to solve the ode, and not just the call to `jac`.  The ode solver has to convert the list of lists returned by your lambda expression into an array at some point.

Comment: good idea. I'm eager to learn this, As I need to speed up a particle filter.

Comment: Result: no notable difference. Interesting.

Comment: "When the solver completes, set `tvals = np.unique(tvals)`." I thought about this some more, but if you want `tvals` to represent the number of times the ODE function was evaluated, you should not reduce that value by running `unique`. I do not see why the number of unique time values for which the function was evaluated is specifically interesting, as you do not know which time values are actually used to achieve the final result: some were probably dropped.