# How can I implement a variable step Python integrator that is the same as Matlab's ode15s?

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, ode

I need an efficient Python ODE solver for a stiff problem similar to Matlab's ode15s.

Summary:
- I have converted an ODE system of equations function from Matlab to Python. 
- I have solved the system in Matlab. 
- In Python, I can solve the system using the SciPy vode integrator. 
- The SciPy solver takes ~16x longer than the Matlab ODE solver because it takes ~162x more steps over the same duration.

How can I improve the speed of my solver by decreasing the number of steps required?

I have a system of equations dY/dt, with 23 variables.

My Matlab ODE solver implementation is:

```
duration = [0 .5]

options = odeset('MaxStep',1e-3,'InitialStep',2e-5);
[t,Yc] = ode15s(@funct, duration, Y, options);
```

When I run the above code, it takes ~.5 seconds and finishes in 507 steps.

I converted `funct` to Python and used the SciPy vode integrator with the same settings:

```
solver = ode(funct)
solver.set_integrator('vode', method='bdf', max_step=1e-3, first_step=2e-5)
solver.set_initial_value(Y0, t0)

while solver.successful() and solver.t < t1:
    solver.integrate(t1, step=True)
    csv_writer.writerow([solver.t, solver.y])
```

This implementation takes ~82 seconds and 81,222 steps – this is prohibitively long for the types of simulations I need to run.

I found one post that [recommends calculating the Jacobian to decrease the number of steps made by the solver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33733189/stiff-ode-solver).

Because I cannot calculate the Jacobian directly, I numerically estimate it using the following:

```
def jacobian(time, Y):
    dY_dt = funct(time, Y)

    Y_step = Y + Y * .001

    n=len(Y)
    jac=np.zeros((n, n))

    for column in range(n): #through columns
        Y_step_current = np.copy(Y)
        Y_step_current[column] = Y_step[column]

        dY_dY = funct(time, Y_step_current)

        if (Y_step[column] - Y[column]) != 0:
            jac[column, :] = (dY_dY - dY_dt) / (Y_step[column] - Y[column])

    return jac
```

I know the above implementation is a little clunky, but I'm only interested in decreasing the number of steps.

I pass this Jacobian to the integrator:

```
solver = ode(funct, jac=paciJacobian)
```

This implementation is even slower than the first and requires that I decrease the minimum step size to 1e-8.

In short, how can I implement a variable step Python integrator that is the same as Matlab's ode15s?

Comment: Can you try to use the newer `res=solve_ivp(funct,[t0,t1], Y0,...)` interface with `method=RADAU`? If you give no `t_eval` array, this will return the internal step points in the arrays `res.t` and `res.y`, if you set `dense_output=True` you get in `res.sol` a piecewise polynomial interpolation function.

Comment: It’s hard to answer your question without knowing your actual differential equation. However, if you have that many equations, [this module of mine](https://github.com/neurophysik/jitcode) could considerably speed things up (and automatically derive the Jacobian on top). Also note that there is little point in approximating the Jacobian via finite differences, because this is what most implicit solvers do if you do not provide an explicit Jacobian.

Comment: Thank you both for your quick responses. @Wrzlprmft, the JiTCODE module is terrific. I was able to run the code with the `'dopri5'` integrator. Unfortunately, my solution accumulated a bit too much error. Now, I am struggling to implement the `'vode'` method. The code gets hung up and errors after outputting:
`generated symbolic Jacobian` I cloned the JiTCODE repo and ran tests. I get the error: `clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp' - ERROR: test_omp(test_generation.TestBasic)`
 Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @apc5un: Can you please raise an issue [here](https://github.com/neurophysik/jitcode/issues/), in particular stating your system specifications.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I added an issue called [test_omp fails when running vode integrator](https://github.com/neurophysik/jitcode/issues/14). Thank you again for your help.